AWS CodeBuild Fails with YAML_FILE_ERROR When Running Python Script in buildspec.yml
I’m trying to run a Python script in AWS CodeBuild using a buildspec.yml file. The Python script is supposed to send an email using AWS SES. Here’s the relevant part of my buildspec.yml:
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      python: 3.8
    commands:
      - pip install boto3
  build:
    commands:
      - |
        echo "import os
        import boto3
        from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
        from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
        from email.mime.text import MIMEText
        from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication

        SUBJECT='There are high or medium alerts..'
        SENDER='xxx'
        RECIPIENT='xxx'
        ATTACHMENT='$CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR/scan-result/compressed_report.zip'
        BODY_TEXT = 'Please check file for report'

        # The HTML body of the email.
        BODY_HTML = '''\
        <html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
        <h1>Hello!</h1>
        <p>Please see the attached file for a list of customers to contact.</p>
        </body>
        </html>
        '''

        CHARSET = 'utf-8'

        # Create a new SES resource and specify a region.
        client = boto3.client('ses')

        # Create a multipart/mixed parent container.
        msg = MIMEMultipart('mixed')
        # Add subject, from and to lines.
        msg['Subject'] = SUBJECT 
        msg['From'] = SENDER 
        msg['To'] = RECIPIENT

        # Create a multipart/alternative child container.
        msg_body = MIMEMultipart('alternative')

        # Encode the text and HTML content and set the character encoding. This step is
        # necessary if you're sending a message with characters outside the ASCII range.
        textpart = MIMEText(BODY_TEXT.encode(CHARSET), 'plain', CHARSET)
        htmlpart = MIMEText(BODY_HTML.encode(CHARSET), 'html', CHARSET)

        # Add the text and HTML parts to the child container.
        msg_body.attach(textpart)
        msg_body.attach(htmlpart)

        # Define the attachment part and encode it using MIMEApplication.
        att = MIMEApplication(open(ATTACHMENT, 'rb').read())

        # Add a header to tell the email client to treat this part as an attachment,
        # and to give the attachment a name.
        att.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment',filename=os.path.basename(ATTACHMENT))

        # Attach the multipart/alternative child container to the multipart/mixed
        # parent container.
        msg.attach(msg_body)

        # Add the attachment to the parent container.
        msg.attach(att)
        #print(msg)
        try:
            #Provide the contents of the email.
            response = client.send_raw_email(
                Source=SENDER,
                Destinations=[
                    RECIPIENT
                ],
                RawMessage={
                    'Data':msg.as_string(),
                },
                ConfigurationSetName=CONFIGURATION_SET
            )
        # Display an error if something goes wrong. 
        except ClientError as e:
            print(e.response['Error']['Message'])
        else:
            print('Email sent! Message ID:'),
            print(response['MessageId'])" > script.py
      - python script.py

However, when I run the build, I get the following error:
YAML_FILE_ERROR Message: could not find expected ':' at line xx(the line of echo "import os)

I’ve tried enclosing the Python code in double quotes and using single quotes inside the Python code, but the error persists. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Just solved this problem by using yaml grammar checker and found the indentation is the cause. I need to give it 4 spaces to - for each line, I dont know the reason. But problem fixed.
- | 
    echo "import os
    import boto3
    ...

